# Is there a way to get audio file length Python Pyglet

Tags: python, pyglet

I am working with pyglet and was wondering if there was a way to get full audio file length? The only way of getting the time that I am aware of is the player.time function.

Code:

```
import pyglet

player = pyglet.media.Player()
sound = pyglet.media.load("My Movie.wav", streaming=False)
player.queue(sound)
player.play()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`.duration` property](http://pyglet.readthedocs.org/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/media/pyglet.media.Source.html?highlight=duration#pyglet.media.Source.duration):

```
sound.duration
```

> The length of the source, in seconds.
>
> Not all source durations can be determined; in this case the value is
>   None.